# Conda: Downloading a package and updating it

Tags: python, package, conda

Using Python 2.7, I am trying to download a package from Anaconda.org, increase its version number by 0.1 (i.e ver 0.0 to ver 0.1), and then re-upload it to the same Anaconda channel. My code is saved in a .py file that is used in Window's cmd or iPython

So far in my .py file I have:

```
import sys, subprocess, conda

# Search for the package
search = subprocess.check_output(['conda', 'search', 'gladio'])

# Take version number from package
v = [int(s) for s in search.split() if s.isdigit()]

# Update with new version number
v = v[0] + 1
print 'New version number is 0.%s' % v

# Set new commands as strings
pack = '''!conda package -p C:\Users\Ian\Anaconda\gladio --pkg-name gladio -
       -pkg-ver 0.%s''' % v
load = '!anaconda upload gladio0.%s-0.tar.bz2' % v

# Execute strings
exec pack
exec load
```

However I get this as a response in the terminal:

```
New version number is 0.1
  File "<string>", line 1
    !conda package -p C:\Users\Ian\Anaconda\gladio --pkg-name gladi...
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

***However if I copy and paste as raw text into iPython it works.***

When deleting the exclamation mark I get:

```
conda package -p C:\Users\Ian\Anaconda\gladio --pkg-name gladi...
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried changing to

```
eval pack
eval load
```

or

```
eval $pack
eval $load
```

with no luck. I also tried defining a 'pack' and a 'load' but I get the same syntax error. I know I'm supposed to avoid the exec and eval functions but I'm not sure what to do here. I have the exact same issue when using Window's cmd, Spyder, or iPython.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the exclamation `! code here` syntax is valid in IPython (and Jupyter Notebooks) as a means to run shell commands. However, it is not valid syntax for the general (regular) Python interpreter that runs when you type `python script_name.py` in the CMD. Although not well documented, there is a `conda.cli.python_api` and `conda.exports`. You can find the code for the former here: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/cli/python_api.py